# PHP Stop script file_get_contents() after 2 seconds

Tags: php

Okay so I have a PHP script that loads another page using `file_get_contents()`.

The other page takes around 30 seconds to load (the type of script it is), and all I need is the `file_get_contents()` is to initiate this script.

The problem is, the `file_get_contents()` will stay loading for the whole 30 seconds. The only way to stop this is to close the tab (when closing the tab the script it calls still runs).

So, how can I get it so the `file_get_contents();` closes after say 2 seconds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use file_get_contents() ? If you're simply using it to run another script why not just use curl and route the output of the curl to null.  Or remove the output from the 2nd script and put in a ignore_user_abort(true); on the 2nd script  that way it'll keep running even if you cancel/abort etc the previous command.  Because php is a top to bottom language the next process will always wait for the previous process to complete so your file_get_contents() always has to complete before it can move on.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#82527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't answer your question but I recommend using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead `file_get_contents`.

Example:

```
function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}
```

Your issue may be from the timeout: `default_socket_timeout`

But this doesn't seem logically because 2 seconds is really very few and I can't explain myself why someone would change it to 2 seconds. The default is 60 seconds.

Comment: I'd add CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION also.

Comment: Yep, the OP can add what he wants. This is the minimal one which I'm using for a Google Chrome extension. For example I realized that without setting `User Agent` some websites don't return data at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the [manual page](http://php.net/file_get_contents) we can see that `file_get_contents()` accepts a third argument called `$context` were we are able to fine-tune our options. Following some links from there we reach [HTTP context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) where `timeout` appears to be our man:

> **timeout** float
>
> ```
> Read timeout in seconds, specified by a float (e.g. 10.5).
>
> By default the default_socket_timeout setting is used.
> ```

So you can either provide a context or change [default_socket_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) (first option looks less prone to break other things).

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested it.*

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use [set_time_limit(2)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) before `file_get_contents` function call.

Comment: `set_time_limit` will set the maximum execution time limit for the whole script not just a block of code or a function, witch may break the execution flow of the script if it was big or on high load environment when the appropriate execution time limit not set.